# How do I figure out a root cause of a zombie process?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pid

A process on a production linux server became a zombie with unknown reason. I wonder if there is a certain methodology to find out what causes it.

Comment: Do you know *which* process (program binary) it was?

Comment: @Jens yup, it was one of java programs running on that server. Actually the process became a zombie after I killed stuck java pid.

Comment: Then the process Z may have exited because it could no longer communicate with the process K you killed. But the parent of Z did not expect to collect an exit status this early with `wait()` and thus Z became a zombie.